# LaTeX Error: Unicode character happen with Miktex, but not with Texlive!

Tags: miktex, texlive, unicode

this error happens when I compile with Miktex on a windows machine, but works fine and without error on Texlive:

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character ف (U+0641)not set up for use with LaTeX

here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,includehead,includefoot,marginparwidth=1.5cm,
headheight=25pt,headsep=5pt,bottom=45pt ,showframe,showcrop]{geometry} 

%_______________________________________________________________________________
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[LAE,LFE]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[arabic,french,english]{babel}
%_______________________________________________________________________________

%\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts,amsgen,amsxtra,xspace,mathrsfs}
 
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{fmultico} \setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{shadow}
%_______________________________________________________________________________
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}.}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\large\alph{enumii})}

%_______________________________________________________________________________
\newcounter{exercice}
\setcounter{exercice}{1}
\renewcommand{\theexercice}{\textbf{\LR{\arabic{exercice}}}}
\newcommand{\exo}{\vspace{5pt}\hrule\vspace{5pt}\noindent
\textbf{\uline{\large \RL{تمريـن}} } \theexercice \addtocounter{exercice}{1}: }
\newcommand{\exov}{\noindent\textbf{Exercice} \theexercice
\addtocounter{exercice}{1} : }

%_______________________________________________________________________________
\newcommand{\RL}{\textRL}
\newcommand{\LR}{\textLR}
%_______________________________________________________________________________
\DeclareMathOperator{\e}{e}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathds{R}}
%_______________________________________________________________________________

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{arabic}

\begin{center}
\shabox{\textbf{\textsc{\Huge  فرض محروس رقم   \LR{1}}}  (الدورة \LR{2})}
\end{center} 
\vspace*{-.5cm}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textsc{\large المدة:  ( \LR{2} س})}
\end{center}
\vspace*{-.45cm}

%____________________________Exercice 1 ______________________________________

\exo  \marginpar{\begin{center}
\textbf{\LR{11.5} نقط}
\end{center}}

 نعتبر الدالة $g$ المعرفة  كالتالي : 
$\,g(x)=\e^x-x-1$ . 
\begin{enumerate}[\LR{1})]
\item
 أحسب 
$g'(x)$
ثم ضع جدول تغيرات $g$ .
 \marginpar{\begin{center}
 \LR{1} ن
 \end{center}}
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

can anyone help me

Comment: are both installations up to date?

Comment: `laeenc.dfu` is missing in miktex.

Comment: @daleif yes both istallations are up to date

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , how to fix that ?

Comment: you could just copy it from texlive and place it with your document. You might find things easier to use luatex or xetex rather than pdftex for non latin scripts.

Comment: a real fix would be to make a miktex bug report here https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging which says that arabi is missing this file.